# Spark without SPARK_HOME

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am relatively new to Spark and Scala.

I have a scala application that runs in local mode both on my windows box and a Centos cluster.

- As long as spark is in my classpath (i.e., pom.xml), spark runs as unit tests without the need for a SPARK_HOME. But then how do I set Spark properties such as  spark.driver.memory?
- If I do have an instance of spark running locally, my unit test application seems to ignore it when in local mode. I do not see any output on the spark console suggesting it is using the spark instance I started from the command line (via spark-shell command). Am I mistaken? If not, how do I get my scala application to use that instance?

Comment: What exactly referring to as a "spark instance" you started from the command line?  What did you do to start this?

Comment: spark-shell command which starts up spark

Comment: btw I know this is a neophyte question. I am confused because all the start up guides instruct me to create an apache_home and use spark-shell. But this seems unrelated to spark app development. Which then leads to problems when I want to change properties of spark...which cannot be done from SparkSession (or so I have read)

Comment: spark_shell is just an interactive shell, it stands alone and is not an "instance" that other processes should connect to.  When you run your spark application through spark-submit (or just running your spark code) it will start its own instance of spark.  If you need to set any properties they can be bassed in a system properties or through the spark-submit `--conf` parameters,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED to include useful info from comments as well

---

spark_shell is just an interactive shell, it stands alone and is not an "instance" that other processes should connect to. When you run your spark application through spark-submit (or just running your spark code) it will start its own instance of spark. If you need to set any properties they can be bassed in a system properties or through the spark-submit --conf parameters

---

spark-submit requires that first you use maven assembly plugin to compile your application jar and dependencies.
This should then be deployed to the SPARK_HOME directory
Then use the submit script which must also be deployed in SPARK_HOME

The spark-submit script looks like this:

```
./bin/spark-submit   --class xxx.ml.PipelineStart   
--master local[*]   
./xxx/myApp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar   100
```

You can set options in your `SparkConf`. Look at the methods available in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkConf).

There are explicit methods like `SparkConf.setMaster` to set certain properties. However, if you don't see a method to explicitly set a property, then just use `SparkConf.set`. It takes a key and a value, and the configurable properties are all found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

If you're curious about what a property is set to, then you can also use `SparkConf.get` to check that out.

Comment: p.s. You can set `SPARK_HOME` with `SparkConf.setSparkHome`. I haven't really looked into that though, so I can't say too much about it. Just throwin it out there - good luck!